# Where can we find FILE.full publicly for bootstrapping from a snapshot?

Tags: node, bootstrapping, snapshots

In the Nomadic Labs post on Snapshots and History Modes (https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html) , it talks about bootstrapping a Tezos node from a file FILE.full using the following command:

```
$ tezos-node snapshot import FILE.full
```

Where do I obtain this FILE.full publicly if I'm trying to start up my own Tezos node for the first time and quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being you should create it by yourself by exporting it from a trusted full node doing this:

```
tezos-node snapshot export --block BLOCK_HASH FILE.full
```

you can see the full guide here:

https://medium.com/tezos/https-medium-com-tezos-spinning-up-a-tezos-node-in-under-a-few-minutes-3b3328e173f3

This paragraph is interesting and talks about downloading snapshots in the future:

> Hopefully in the future, services will pop up to generate frequent snapshots and publish them for public use. Baking services and block explorers are in an ideal position to do this.

Answer (score 1):

TzDutch provide snapshots via their QuickSync service - https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/

The current latest one is from block `BMKkyoQRCUHh2nLxZE4o6q3ExQDeGntNsdMKTbzq6gEXRg6HguV`

```
wget http://quicksync.tzdutch.com/mainnet-BMKkyoQRCUHh2nLxZE4o6q3ExQDeGntNsdMKTbzq6gEXRg6HguV.full.tar.lz4
lz4 -d mainnet-BMKkyoQRCUHh2nLxZE4o6q3ExQDeGntNsdMKTbzq6gEXRg6HguV.full.tar.lz4 | tar xf -
```